# Why can't I submit my question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I am trying to submit a question to Stack Overflow - but the "Post" button is doing nothing. I just posted a question two hours ago; is there a time limit? The odd thing is that there is no indication if this is intentional or something weird - I'm betting it's intentional because:

1. I submitted a question two hours ago just fine.
2. I switched browsers and it's not working.

I seek enlightenment.

Comment: Cross dupe (MSO): ['Post Your Question' button doesn't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360073/post-your-question-button-doesnt-work)

Comment: BECAUSE ADAM BROKE IT IS WHY

Comment: I am why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Is @AdamLear at it again? I can't post question at Stackoverflow now.

Comment: For a *question ban*, the canonical on Meta Stack Overflow is now *[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers...”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Touching the ask question page is treacherous.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360073/post-your-question-button-doesnt-work/360075#360075)

Answer (score 2):

For others who have this question, there is also the possibility that you've typed a string of characters that Stack Exchange rejects.

For example, this file header data:

[image]

If attempting to edit an existing post you will most likely see an error:

[image]

If posting for the first time you may not see any indication of why you can't proceed.

*Usually* enclosing characters in [backticks](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm) is enough to let Stack Exchange know not to try to interpret a string of text. But apparently there are exceptions where backticks don't work.